# Existence of a function with a certain property on a subset of the cantor set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, cantor-set

Let $\mathcal{C} \subset [0,1]$ denote the usual Cantor set (i.e. the usual definition based on removed middle third open intervals succesively). Define $S = \mathcal{C} - E$ where $E$ is the set $\{0,1 \} \cup E'$, and $E'$ is the set of all endpoints of all the middle third open intervals successively removed from $[0,1]$ to construct the usual cantor set $\mathcal{C}$.

My question is, does there exist a function $f : S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq  0}$ with the following properties:

(i) If $\{s_n \}_{n \geq 1} \subset S$ satisfies $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} s_n = s$, for $s \in S$, and $\lim_{n} f(s_n) \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ exists, then $\lim_{n} f(s_n) = f(s)$. In other words $\mathcal{G}(f)$ is closed (since it is sequentially closed and both $S$ and $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ are first countable).

(ii) If $\{s_n \}_{n \geq 1} \subset S$ satisfies $\lim_{n} s_n = e \in E$, then $\lim_{n} f(s_n) = +\infty$

Edit (25th August) : As pointed out by mihaild, $\liminf_{n} f(s_n), \limsup_{n} f(s_n)$ must both be $\infty$ in (ii). I have updated (ii) accordingly

Comment: Just to be clear, in the ternary definition of the Cantor set which drops all numbers from $[0,1]$ with a $1$ in their ternary expression, your $S$ does that and also drops all numbers whose expression ends with a recurring $000\ldots$ or $222\ldots$ i.e. those which are $\frac{a}{3^b}$ for integer $a$ and $b$

Comment: @Henry yes exactly